# How to access the textbox in a RowUpdating event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events, gridview

So I have a GridView and I added a Row Updating event. It by default shows text boxes whenever I click it. But I have no idea about how to access the values of those text boxes as they don't have any ID. Below is the code I am trying to write but it keeps saying index out of bound at Controls[0].

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
    //TextBox category = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl()
    //int userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    //TextBox textCat = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
    TextBox textDes = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
    TextBox textPrice = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
    TextBox textdrcr = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblExp2 set description='" + textDes.Text + "',price='" + textPrice.Text + "',description='" + textdrcr.Text + "'where id='" + id + "'", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    GVBind();
}
```

Below is the GVBind function

```
void GVBind()
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select categoryName as Category, description as Description, price as Price, drcr from tblExp2 where id = " + id, con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some of your code? This would make your question a lot more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using find control and Row index. in the event you need write some like this.

```
TextBox mytxtbox= (TextBox)gridview.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtId");
```

In the event you can find e.RowIndex

```
string myText= mytxtbox.text;
```

Comment: I clicked on edit columns and added the edit column on grid view. When I run my project and click on edit, it shows text boxes for all the fields for me to edit. But they dont have any ID so I dont know how to access them

Comment: can you add the GridView1 code for 'textDes' column